# bootcamp earphones constant high pitch sound regardless of sound level

Tags: windows, audio, bootcamp, sound-volume, ear-phones

I installed windows 10 and everything was running smoothly until a day later when my earphones suddenly started emitting a high pitch noise whenever any sound was played at a constant level.

It is pretty much unusable unless I want tinnitus :( I'm not sure what the issue is, I’ve tried reinstalling the drivers but that hasn’t helped.

I have cirrus logic cs8409 (ab 51) drivers and when I switch drivers to generic or endpoint, I get no audio.

Comment: I have the same problem. Nothing helped - even reinstall of windows.

Answer (score 0):

I've installed the Windows 11 Preview instead of Windows 10 and it's helped.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why this worked, but this person's solution did the trick: https://www.reddit.com/r/bootcamp/comments/pwy9xp/high_pitched_sound_when_plugging_in_earphones/hesbd6g/?context=3

I had my computer set to automatically boot into Windows, but holding down option (Alt on a windows keyboard) during boot, and then selecting the windows partition fixed it!

Comment: WHat is the solution - the answer should be given here and only use a link to provide extra information or to provide a citation of where the answer came from.

Comment: The second paragraph explains exactly what I did to fix it.